# HP proliant microserver won't boot

Tags: hardware, hp, boot

I was installing an ethernet driver for VPN on an HP Microserver (on PCI 1).
Then, suddenly the server shut down while I was installing it.

When I tried to  boot it back up it only shows the health light as red with stand by orange light on the power switch.

I am afraid I may have shorted out the NMI. I did everything I could do now, BIOS reset, removed HDD.

Could anyone help?!

Comment: Hmmm... I think you don't really understand what an electrical short circuit is.

Comment: I don't think he knows what a NMI is either.

Comment: Or, indeed, an ethernet driver.

Comment: well, I am sorry for being quite dumb.I am just a student who is interested in computer in Korea,whet do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

You were installing a Ethernet Network Card while the server was running??

Remove all power (unplug everything from the back). Remove the network card. Plug in only the power cord, try turning it on. If you still get the red light you have probably fried something.

Comment: actually, I was removing the ethernet card. Then the disaster,it suddenly turned off and when I plug it back, It shows stand by light with amber on health light. No responding at any action. And also,I think the thing that is causing the problem is the NMI. I think I killed that

Comment: Installing or removing a card while the system is running can destroy it as you experienced. How do you even get the idea to do something like that? Also, what do you think is an NMI and how did you kill it?

Comment: I am relly ashamed of myself that I did this operation while powered up.The reason why I am so sure that NMI kiled it, is because,while taking the ethernet card out, I got hit by something,then it shutteddown, I found out that the NMI jumper was close and also, I didn't have any jumper or cover on it so.

Comment: you think it could be possible to fix it?

Comment: An NMI would crash Windows (without debugging software to catch the NMI), but wouldn't do any permanent damage to the hardware. If you followed the directions in my Answer and it still has the red light, it's fried. If that's the case you can buy a new motherboard from HP...

Comment: do you have any idea where can I get one in korea?